# Upgrading to MYSQL 8 - MAMP

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp, mysql-8.0

I have installed MAMP on my MAC machine and I am trying to upgrade it to use MySQL 8. However, I am not having any luck. I have tried following script but database migration fails.

Also, sequelPro fails to connect to DB but, phpmyadmin has no issue connecting.

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -OL https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xfvz mysql-8.0.*

echo "stopping mamp"
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh
sudo killall httpd mysqld

echo "creating backup"
sudo rsync -arv --progress /Applications/MAMP ~/Desktop/MAMP-Backup

echo "copy bin"
sudo rsync -arv --progress mysql-8.0.*/bin/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ --exclude=mysqld_multi --exclude=mysqld_safe 

echo "copy share"
sudo rsync -arv --progress mysql-8.0.*/share/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/

echo "fixing access (workaround)"
sudo chmod -R o+rw  /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
sudo chmod -R o+rw  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/
#sudo chmod -R o+rw  "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/"

echo "starting mamp"
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh

echo "migrate to new version"
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root --password=root -h 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @flakerimi I'm not sure, but Sequel Pro is having issues with MySQL 8, not to the MAMP. I had 8 version install with Docker on my macbook and Sequel still was having issues. Used navicat for 8th version.

Comment: The last I read, SequelPro does not support MySQL 8, I use TablePlus for that.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when running this script: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you tell us what all you tried? for suppose: did make sure that your MySQL 8 installation is working independently without MAMP; did you use the `mysqldump` command to export your databases from the old version, and then import them into the new MySQL 8 version.

Comment: @JoyNa I performed a full backup of the necessary databases using ```mysqldump``` before upgrading in MAMP. After the upgrade, I restored the databases from the backup file.